# How to give multiple part files into Path

Tags: hadoop, path, mapreduce

I am trying to give multiple part files as Path.

```
out 
 |
 |__ part-r-00000
 |__ part-r-00001
 |
 |__ ...
 |
 |__ ...
```

How to give this as Path?

```
Path getall = new Path(____);
```

Please suggest

**UPDATE**

As Alexey Shestakov suggested I did

```
Path more = new Path("out");
String line2 = null;
Path pathPattern = new Path(more, "part-r-*");
FileStatus [] list = fs.globStatus(pathPattern);
 for (FileStatus status : list) {
    BufferedReader bf21 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pathPattern)));
     while ((line2 = bf21.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println("Line "+line2);
       }
 }
```

But showing

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File out/part-r-* does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File out/part-r-* does not exist.
```

I have a folder named `out` and it contains `part-r-00000 and part-r-00001`
And I am able to read it when I give

```
 Path pathPattern = new Path("out/part-r-0000");
```

Still I am not able to read all part files in a specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use wildcards in path name, for example `new Path("/out/part-r-*")` or `new Path("/out/part-r-?????")`. To get all paths that satisfy the given name you could use method [globStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29).
2. If you want to process these files with map reduce job, then you could give `new Path("/out")` as input path.

Comment: Please see my update...I did as u adviced but could not solve.

Comment: You should replace `pathPattern` with `status.getPath()` in this line: `BufferedReader bf21 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pathPattern)));`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you have to create 2 different paths for the 2 files :

```
Path p0 = new Path("/out/part-r-00000");
Path p1 = new Path("/out/part-r-00001");
```

And so you can do :

```
Path p2 = new Path(p0,p1);
```

I guess it's what you wanted to do ?

Comment: Can I give regular expressions along with that.This will only be applicable for o and 1 part file .something like part-r-[0-9]*

Comment: In your case you have to create a Path per file. You have to check your directory and do some test to check name of files.